# How to write multiple component nested conjunctions constraints in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'd like to be able to select for all rows that contain two sets of double conditions.

As an example I am dealing with a population that is divided into different districts that change from year to year. I want to query for the subset of all people that were part of one district in one year and another district in another year.

As first thought I wrote the following statement:

```
session.Query(People).join(District, People.district).filter(and_(and_(District.year == 2015, District.num == 5), and_(District.year == 2016, District.num == 6))).all()
```

However this produces the SQL (summarized):

```
SELECT * FROM database.table JOIN district ON address.district WHERE district.year == 2015 AND district.num == 5 AND district.year == 2016 AND district.num == 6
```

There are no people like this.

The desired SQL statement would be something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM database.table JOIN district ON address.district WHERE ( district.year == 2015 AND district.num == 5 ) AND ( district.year == 2016 AND district.num == 6 )
```

**CLARIFICATION 1**: Changed the SQL statements and added a little more explanation below.

So to clarify, there are districts every year but they change, so each district has a year attached to it. I'm looking for the subset of people that belonged to one district one year and another, overlapping district the next year.

In the end I just pulled all the people from one district then created a FOR loop that would select for those people that belonged to the second district another year but that was an expensive and time consuming solution. I know that there is a way to perform this query (in SET THEORY this would be referred to as the intersection of two sets).

Comment: No. I didn't explain myself well. I'm looking for the intersection of two different data sets, those should, in fact, be AND statements (I think that is)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply your set knowledge in SQL and SQLAlchemy using [`Query.intersect()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.intersect):

```
q1 = session.query(People).\
    join(People.district).\
    filter(District.year == 2015, District.num == 5)

q2 = session.query(People).\
    join(People.district).\
    filter(District.year == 2016, District.num == 6)

q = q1.intersect(q2)
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact, just after I posted the clarification it dawned on me what terminology I should have been using to Google a response. Thanks for this.

Comment: Removed the part about joins, since I think it could've been misinterpreted. They are worth learning, since they're really powerful in relational databases/SQL, though sometimes a bit daunting at first, if having to do self joins, or joins to same table multiple times etc.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your clarification I have updated my answer. You will need to use some identifier for each person that remains the same across years/districts. I have called this person_id. If your identifying feature is spread across multiple columns, then this query will change slightly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.person_id , ... 
FROM database.table AS t1
INNER JOIN database.table AS t2
  ON t2.person_id = t1.person_id
WHERE 
  (t1.year =='2015' AND t1.district == 5) 
AND 
  (t2.year =='2016' AND t2.district ==6)
```

A `DISTINCT` is needed to filter out duplicate rows. If you are performing `Aggregate` type functions, then you may also need a `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself well originally. I've updated the question to reflect what I'm trying to do. In short, what you've proposed would be the union of two different sets of data, I'm only looking for the intersection. Thank you for the response, I hope I've described my issue a little better now.

Comment: Thanks Edward. This would be the correct SQL answer, although I'm using the ORM instead and found that the .intersect method does what I need it to do: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.intersect

Comment: All good, I'll leave it up in case it works for someone else. If `Query.Intersect` works how one would expect, then these should do the same thing.